# How do I pass variables and tables through functions on Lua?

Tags: arrays, lua, parameter-passing, love2d

I'm trying to simplify my code by putting everything through functions, but I don't think that the variables and tables are passing through the arguments in my code, or **nodeNumber** isn't working properly, because every time I run my code I receive the error *attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value*. I'm using LOVE to create graphics. I'm attempting to create a graph to show all the possible outcomes when using a betting strategy (i.e. Every time you win a round, you set your bet back to 1, but every time you lose a round, you double your previous bet. The layer number indicates the amount of rounds played so far, v represents value (The aggregate of money you have made or lost so far.), b represents bet (Your next bet for the following round that follows the strategy I mentioned before.), and each node is every dollar amount and at every layer calculated so far.

```
layer0v = {0}
layer0b = {1}
layer1v = {}
layer1b = {}
xValues = {0}
nodeNumber = 1
curLayer = 1
canvWidth = 800
canvHeight = 512

function love.load()
    love.window.setMode(canvWidth, canvHeight)
end

repeat
    table.insert(xValues, (#xValues + 1), xValues[#xValues] + 5)
until (xValues[#xValues] == canvWidth)

function calculateX(curLayer, xValues)
    value = xValues[curLayer]
    return value
end

function calculateWV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber)
    value = prevLayerV[nodeNumber] + prevLayerB[nodeNumber]
    return value
end

function calculateLV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber)
    value = prevLayerV[nodeNumber] - prevLayerB[nodeNumber]
    return value
end

function calculateWB()
    value = 1
    return value
end

function calculateLB(prevLayerB, nodeNumber)
    value = prevLayerB[nodeNumber] * 2
    return value
end

function addToTable(curLayerV, curLayerB, prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber)
    table.insert(curLayerV, (#curLayerV + 1), calculateWV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber))
    table.insert(curLayerV, (#curLayerV + 1), calculateLV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber))
    table.insert(curLayerB, (#curLayerB + 1), calculateWB())
    table.insert(curLayerB, (#curLayerB + 1), calculateLB(prevLayerB, nodeNumber))
end

function drawLine(curLayerV, curLayerB, curLayerX, prevLayerV, prevLayerB, prevLayerX, nodeNumber)
    love.graphics.line(prevLayerX, (prevLayerV[nodeNumber] + 128), curLayerX, (calculateWV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber) + 128))
    love.graphics.line(prevLayerX, (prevLayerV[nodeNumber] + 128), curLayerX, (calculateLV(prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber) + 128))
end

function createLayer(curLayerV, curLayerB, prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber, curLayer, xValues)
    nodeNumber = 1
    repeat
        addToTable(curLayerV, curLayerB, prevLayerV, prevLayerB, nodeNumber)
        drawLine(curLayerV, curLayerB, calculateX(curLayer, xValues), prevLayerV, prevLayerB, calculateX((curLayer - 1), xValues))
        if (nodeNumber ~= #prevLayerV) then
            nodeNumber = nodeNumber + 1
        end
    until (nodeNumber == #prevLayerV)
end

function love.load()
    createLayer(layer1v, layer1b, layer0v, layer0b, nodeNumber, curLayer, xValues)
end
```

I've tried using **break** to exit the line once **nodeNumber** is equal to **prevLayerV**. I've tried converting **nil** to 0 so the computer can do arithmetic it (even though this wouldn't achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: You are only passing 6 arguments to `drawLine`, instead of 7 (missing `nodeNumber`). That's only the beginning of your problems though. This code is a *mess* of [shadowed variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), and is very hard to parse. Suggested reading: [§2.3 – Variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.3) and [§2.6 – Visibility Rules](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.6). Additionally, attempting to draw things outside of the [`love.draw`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.draw) callback is a bad idea.

Comment: Aside: [`table.insert`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.insert) already defaults to inserting at the end of the table (`#t + 1`).

Comment: In `createLayer`, the initial return value of `calculateX((curLayer - 1), xValues)` is `nil`. This is because the initial value of `curLayer` is `1`, which results in `xValues[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent all day trying to figure this out, and, thanks to you, it's working! I'll try to clean up these variables and `table.insert` commands. Thanks for helping me clean it up! The problem was with `drawLine` and `xValues[0]` but those were easy fixes.

Comment: And i suggest strongly to  learn this: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.load - Look at the Example how to use ```local``` defined in the aftewards defined - Your Program should run in ```love.update()``` and ```love.draw()```. Define that too. Also you probably want a ```conf.lua```? - Look for it on the Wiki: https://love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
-- main.lua -- Easy Screen Change by Function Change (Endless Loop)
local txt1, txt2, start, stop, fnc1, fnc2
local love, os = require("love"), require("os")

function love.load() -- Only at Start
txt1 = {{0,1,0}, "GO", {1,1,0}, "GO", {1,0,0}, "GO"} -- Colored Text
txt2 = {{love.math.random(),love.math.random(),love.math.random()}, "GAME OVER"} -- Random Color
start = os.time()
stop = 10
fnc1 = function() love.graphics.print(txt1, 10, 10) end -- Green Yellow Red
fnc2 = function() love.graphics.print(txt2, 10, 10) end -- Random Color
love.draw = fnc1 -- Construct love.draw() and Start with fnc1
end

function love.update()
if os.time() > start + stop then
  love.draw = fnc2 -- Change to Game Over Screen
elseif os.time() > start + (stop * 2) then
  love.event.quit("restart") -- Restart
end
end
-- love.draw() will be constructed by love.load() at every start/restart
-- After start/restart love.draw() will be changed from love.update() by condition
```